# The recovery of .p2 folder. Eclipse is not gettting start

Tags: java, eclipse

In windows, I deleted .p2 forlder due to some personal reason.  Since luncher for eclipse was present in .p2 folder as below directory:
**--launcher.library
C:\Users\XXXX.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740**
So eclipse is not getting started.
Please can any body suggests how to recover the .p2 folder in windows 10 without re-install the eclipse. 
Eclipse version - Neon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. By deleting the *.p2* folder, you deleted almost everything except a few configuration and other small files. The folder *.p2\poll* contains not only the launcher plug-in but also all other plug-ins, the binaries of all Eclipse applications that have been installed via the *[Eclipse Installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer)*.

Comment: Thanks for proving more clarification related .p2. I reinstalled the eclipse, which created the .p2 folder again.

Comment: But, when I want to uninstall/remove Eclipse then I can delete this folder - right?

Comment: @PeterVARGA Yes, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Eclipse Again. then .p2 folder will create by default.